# How can I place two inputs side by side>

Tags: css, django, django-forms

I am working with Django Forms and I want to place two input fields side by side but don't have a wrapper on them so is there any way I can do that through css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not experienced with Django, but you could try inline display.

```
input {
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it was the first thing I tried too but didn't seem to work